# Changing file type in Intellij IDEA for settings.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, file-type

I'm working on python project in IDEA and have xml file named "settings.xml"

IDEA recognizes this file as maven configuration file and apply specific validation rules and my file marked by red error underlining

How can I mark this file as not maven file?

Answer (score 1):

You can ingnore this file in maven plugin settings.

> File -> Settings -> Maven -> Ignored Files

[image: maven settings]

Comment: Hm... there is nothing, no files to choose

Comment: Ty use "settings.xml" in path patterns field.